# Read multiple lines stored in a text file and format it in bash

Tags: text-processing, command-line

The data in my text file and the output format expected is as shown.

[image: IMage 1]

I tried:

```
cat test2.txt | tr -d "\t"
```

But that's not working. Please help. As I have to read the file in the expected output format and do further loop processing.

Comment: It is much harder for us to help you if you do not post actual data.  Images are hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
BEGIN { RS = "" ; }

{
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7
}
```

produces:

```
WEBA 30-MAR-17 NA NOT_STARTED 01-APR-17 25-MAR-17 Target_Not_Started
WEBA 29-MAR-17 NA NOT_STARTED 01-APR-17 25-MAR-17 Target_Not_Started
WEBA 28-MAR-17 NA STARTED 01-APR-17 25-MAR-17 Target_Started
```

Comment: A bit more compactly `awk '{$1=$1} 1' RS= test.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver this warrants being an answer in its own right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. awk '{$1=$1} 1' RS= test.txt worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash if you need.  Using a loop and an if condition like:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="/root/a.txt"

while  read -r line
do
 if [ "$line" != "" ]; then

 echo $line |tr -d "\n"

else
 echo   ""
fi

done <"$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl

```
perl -l -00pe 'y/\n/ /' yourfile | column -t
```

## Sed

```
< yourfile \
   sed -ne '
      /^WEBA/,/^$/!d
      /^$/g
      s/\n/ /gp
      H
      /^WEBA/h
   ' \
| column -t
```